# Map JSON in a list in a Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a string list in integer list associating its ids in a dataframe column.

That's because I need to map a list of sports per id like the next shows. There are sports which are not in the JSON. In that case, it's necessary to remove that element in the desired dataframe with integer list column.

That's the JSON I have to map:

```
[ 
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Karate",
   }, 
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Paintball",
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Rugby",
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Squash",
   },
   {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Softball",
   },
   {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Swimiming",
   },
   {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Weighlifting",
   },
   {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Table Tennis",
   },
   {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Tenpin Bowling",
   }
]
```

That's the dataframe I have, with sports that are not in the JSON.

```py
id        sports             
111       ['Softball', 'Table Tennis', 'Rafting']                     
222       ['Rugby', 'Tenpin Bowling','Squash'] 
333       ['Weighlifting', 'Tennis', 'Swimiming'] 
444       ['Softball', 'Table Tennis', 'Paintball']
555       ['Rugby', 'Tenpin Bowling','Squash']
666       ['Weighlifting', 'Karate', 'Swimiming']
777       ['Softball', 'Table Tennis', 'Soccer'] 
888       ['Basketball', 'Tenpin Bowling','Squash']
999       ['Weighlifting', 'Karate', 'Swimiming']
```

And that's the dataframe I need, without sports that couldn't be mapped in the JSON.

```py
id        sports             
111       [5, 8]                     
222       [3, 9, 4] 
333       [7, 6] 
444       [5, 8, 2]
555       [3, 9, 4]
666       [7, 1, 6] 
777       [5, 8] 
888       [9, 4]
999       [7, 1, 6]
```

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the list of dicts with sports codes is in a file, `test.json`, load it into `data`

  - If the list of dicts is already loaded, then just skip loading the file part, and replace `data` with the name of the variable you're using.
- This answer assumes the values in the `sports` column are lists, and not strings

  - If the `sports` column contents are strings, then use `df.sports = df.sports.apply(literal_eval)`
- If you want to replace the `sports` column with the codes, use `df['sports'] =` 
  instead of `df['codes'] =`

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd


# if the list of dicts is in a file, load it with the following
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = literal_eval(f.read())

# data is the object now holding the list of dicts
# convert data to a dict
dd = {d['name']: d['id'] for d in data}

# add a codes column for the sports in dd
df['codes'] = df.sports.apply(lambda x: [dd.get(v) for v in x if v in dd])

# display df
    id                                sports      codes
0  111     [Softball, Table Tennis, Rafting]     [5, 8]
1  222       [Rugby, Tenpin Bowling, Squash]  [3, 9, 4]
2  333     [Weighlifting, Tennis, Swimiming]     [7, 6]
3  444   [Softball, Table Tennis, Paintball]  [5, 8, 2]
4  555       [Rugby, Tenpin Bowling, Squash]  [3, 9, 4]
5  666     [Weighlifting, Karate, Swimiming]  [7, 1, 6]
6  777      [Softball, Table Tennis, Soccer]     [5, 8]
7  888  [Basketball, Tenpin Bowling, Squash]     [9, 4]
8  999     [Weighlifting, Karate, Swimiming]  [7, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a `mappings` dictionary from the json `data` by initializing a dataframe from this json `data` and using [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html), then use this `mappings` dictionary to map each sport in list to the corresponding `id`:

```
mappings = pd.read_json(data).set_index('name')['id'].to_dict()
df['sports'] = [[mappings[key] for key in lst if key in mappings] for lst in df['sports']]
```

OR, it is also possible to use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), but this approach is generally *slower*:

```
mappings = pd.read_json(data).set_index('name')['id']
df['sports'] = (
    df['sports'].explode()
    .map(mappings).dropna().astype(int).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
    id     sports
0  111     [5, 8]
1  222  [3, 9, 4]
2  333     [7, 6]
3  444  [5, 8, 2]
4  555  [3, 9, 4]
5  666  [7, 1, 6]
6  777     [5, 8]
7  888     [9, 4]
8  999  [7, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your previous question. I modified my previous answer to handle this case and `NaN` and non-list elements. Let's call the json string as `l_str`

```
df_map = pd.read_json(l_str)
d = dict(zip(df_map.name, df_map.id))
df['sports'] = [[d.get(y) for y in x if y in d] 
                       for x in df.sports if isinstance(x, list)]

Out[51]:
    id     sports
0  111     [5, 8]
1  222  [3, 9, 4]
2  333     [7, 6]
3  444  [5, 8, 2]
4  555  [3, 9, 4]
5  666  [7, 1, 6]
6  777     [5, 8]
7  888     [9, 4]
8  999  [7, 1, 6]
```